# Print skipping newline

Tags: python, multithreading, newline

I've got a question based off an answer I saw. It uses a thread pool to manage threads but each thread prints `'Going to sleep... i'`, sleeps for `i` time and then prints `'Slept..'`. my question is why it prints `'Going to sleep...Going to sleep...Going to sleep...'`? It doesn't print them on a newline unless I explicitly add `\n` to the end of the string. Here is my output without the `\n`.
`

```
Going to sleep...Going to sleep...Going to sleep...


Slept ..0
Going to sleep...
Slept ..1
Going to sleep...
Slept ..2
Slept ..3
Slept ..4
done!!`
```

Here is my output with the newline

```
Going to sleep...
Going to sleep...
Going to sleep...



Slept ..0
Going to sleep...

Slept ..1
Going to sleep...

Slept ..2
Slept ..3
Slept ..4
done!!
```

The spaces between `Going to sleep...` and the first `Slept..` seem strange to me as well.

Here's the code

```
import time
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def run(i):
    print "Going to sleep...\n"
    time.sleep(i)
    print ("Slept .." + str(i))

p = Pool(3)

res = [p.apply_async(run, (i,)) for i in range(5)]

p.close()
p.join()

print "done!!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `print` statement first writes your text to `sys.stdout`, and once that is written, a separate bytecode handles writing the `\n` newline character:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('print "Hello world!"', '<demo>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello world!')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the separate `PRINT_ITEM` and `PRINT_NEWLINE` bytecodes in the disassembly.

When using `print` in a multi-threaded environment, you can end up switching threads between those two distinct steps; threads 1, 2 and 3 can all end up writing the printed message first, switch threads, and only after the other thread has written their message is the newline written.

By adding `\n` to your message instead, you make sure that the newline is written at the same time. You really are writing *two* newlines to `sys.stdout` in that case.

Comment: so is it reasonable to think you should use `sys.stdout.write` and explicitly write all the `\n` instead of using print in order to avoid this issue?

Comment: @SirParselot: you could indeed write to `sys.stdout` directly. Take into account that race conditions can still take place between distinct `write()` calls.

Comment: You would have race conditions between `print()` calls too though, right?